# N-pair loss vs InfoNCE?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions

I was reading [this awesome blog](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2021/05/31/contrastive-representation-learning.html#infonce)

And it introduces two losses:

- N-pair loss

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}_\text{N-pair}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}^+, \{\mathbf{x}^-_i\}^{N-1}_{i=1}) 
&= \log\big(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \exp(f(\mathbf{x})^\top f(\mathbf{x}^-_i) - f(\mathbf{x})^\top f(\mathbf{x}^+))\big) \\
&= -\log\frac{\exp(f(\mathbf{x})^\top f(\mathbf{x}^+))}{\exp(f(\mathbf{x})^\top f(\mathbf{x}^+)) + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \exp(f(\mathbf{x})^\top f(\mathbf{x}^-_i))}
\end{aligned}
$$

- InfoNCE loss

$$
\mathcal{L}_\text{InfoNCE} = - \mathbb{E} \Big[\log \frac{f(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{c})}{\sum_{\mathbf{x}' \in X} f(\mathbf{x}', \mathbf{c})} \Big]
$$

I think the InfoNCE loss can be better understood by papers like [MOCO](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.05722.pdf) in which the loss is defined as

For query $q$ we have a set of keys $\{ k_1, ..., k_N\}$ where among those $N$ keys there is 1 positive key $k_+$, and InfoNCE is
$$
\mathcal{L}_q = - \log\dfrac{\exp(q k_+ / \tau)}{\sum_i \exp(q k_i / \tau)}
$$

Now my question is, other than the temperature, what are the differences between InfoNCE loss and N-pair loss?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

N-pair loss and InfoNCE are actually the same thing! You could rewrite the InfoNCE loss like this:

[image: equation for InfoNCE, rewritten to spread out the terms in the sum]

This is actually the same as the n-pair loss. Replace $c$ with $x$, $x$ with the positive sample $x^+$, and all other $x'$ with negative samples $x_i^-$. And I changed $f$ to $g$ so that you can rewrite the score function $g(x,c) = \exp{f(x)^T f(c)}$ to match the one from the n-pair loss formulation.

By the way, [the InfoNCE paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.03748.pdf) defines a similar score function with exponential in equation 3. You need the exponential to make the math work out, since it's a softmax.

If you want to learn more, you can check out my blog post about this: [Demystifying Noise Contrastive Estimation](https://jxmo.io/posts/nce)

Comment: Thanks! I guess probably when this loss is used by different work authors just decide to give them different names.

Comment: Yeah. It's worth noting that the [InfoNCE paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.03748.pdf) doesn't cite the [N-pair loss](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2016/hash/6b180037abbebea991d8b1232f8a8ca9-Abstract.html) paper, which came out at least two years earlier. But since the loss is basically just a softmax, maybe the InfoNCE authors didn't think the n-pair loss paper was worth citing. Or maybe they didn't know about this prior work.

Comment: I also think n-pair loss is almost same thing as cross entropy loss with softmax predictions.